# How to get web server error logging output from phpunit functional tests?

Tags: testing

The 500 errors generated during `phpunit` tests aren't showing up in the Apache error logs. Where are those errors logged?

Comment: It's basically wherever your PHP instance is configured to log errors - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834583/where-can-i-find-error-log-files-for-php has some useful info for locating and setting the location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what's going on. Instead of letting Apache log the 500 error, `phpunit` is returning the error message as HTML markup to the call to `$this->drupalGet($path)`.